# If $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, is $X$ independent of $Z$?

Tags: independence

If $X$ is independent of $Y$ and $Y$ is independent of $Z$, is $X$ independent of $Z$? In other words, is independence transitive?

Comment: FAQ.  For much more on this, [here is a focused site search](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=dependent+independent+-sample+-regression+prob*+-disjoint).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. in the extreme case, take for exammple $X=Z$.

Answer (score 2):

You may also think about real life example:

1. $X$ - You find a lottery ticket on the street
2. $Y$ - You flip a coin and get a head
3. $Z$ - You win the lottery.

$X$, $Y$ and $Y$, $Z$ are independent, but lottery ticket for sure help you to win some extra cash.